# No value display in view state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Problem:
I have problem to find a solution that value of txtboxMaxprice will not display if value is 0 or null

Request:
I don't want the txtboxMaxprice value to display in view state if the value is 0 or null in the input textbox.

This source code is made in a simplified version to make more understandable for end users.

// Fullmetalboy

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BokButik1.ViewModels.SokningppPerform2ViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    PerformSearch
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>SökResultat</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Alternativ1", "Sokning", FormMethod.Post))
    { %> 
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Maxprice</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtboxMaxprice" name="txtboxMaxprice" value="<%: Model.Maxprice %>" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Filtrera" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <% } %>    





        //
        // Post: /Sokning/Alternativ1

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Alternativ1(decimal? txtBoxMaxprice)
            {

            var SokningppPerform2ViewModel = new SokningppPerform2ViewModel()
            {

                Maxprice = txtBoxMaxprice)

            };


            return View("PerformSearch", SokningppPerform2ViewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value written into the text box is `null` then it will not display any number.

This should work for you:

```
int? textBoxMaxValue = (Model.MaxPrice > 0) Model.MaxPrice : null;
 <tr>
      <td>Maxprice</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtboxMaxprice" name="txtboxMaxprice" 
         value="<%: textBoxMaxValue %>" /></td>
      <td></td>
 </tr>
```

You can see in this example that if the value of `textBoxMaxValue` is `null` then nothing is written into the `value` attribute of the textbox.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you are still interrested in solving another problem in MVC 2, I have a problem that nobody has solved it yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666775/what-code-in-inherit-part

Comment: I tried your advice and unfortunately I received error message.

Comment: My bad...The type needs to be explicit, it doesn't work with the implivit 'var'. I've updated my answer to reflect this.